# Why Log message can't \n in text file?

Tags: java, logging

I used a function where logger and parameters are initialized.
Although I called this function LogMsg and newline in console, but it gives one single line in the text file. Why is that so?

```
String logmsg="Line1\n"+"Line2\n";

public static void LogMsg(Logger logger,String pathname,Level level,String logmsg){
    //logger=Logger.getLogger("LogMsg");
    FileHandler fh=null;
    try {
        fh = new FileHandler(pathname,300000,1,true);
        fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
         LogRecord record1 = new LogRecord(level, logmsg);
         logger.addHandler(fh);
            logger.log(record1);
            fh.close();

    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to log message due to lack of permissions.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();

        System.out.println("Failed to log message");
    }


}
```

Comment: Which framework do you use, log4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
String logmsg="Line1\r\n"+"Line2\r\n";
```

or better still

```
logmsg = String.Concat("Line1",Environment.NewLine,"Line2",Environment.NewLine);
```

Or better still use a StringBuilder somethimng like

```
logmsg = CreateLogMessage(new string [] {"Line1", "Line2"});

public static CreateLogMessage(string[] argLines);
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(argLines.Length);
  foreach(String line in argLines)
  {
    sb.AppendLine(line);
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Environment.Newline will deal with os differences in terms of which end of line token is expected.

Comment: Damn just noticed the java tag, above is C# should be easy to aadapt though